# Assign to object selected value

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

In JSP in drop down box I have a list of countries. Selected country I should assign to "Organization" object as an object "Country", but I have Bad Request Error.

JSP, **edited**:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@include file='css/styles.css'%>


<html>
<head>
<title>TestWebApp</title>
</head>
<body>
<table align = "center" class="table" cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th valign = "top">Add an organization</th>
</tr>
<form method="POST">
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="${name}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country: </td>
<td>
<%--
<select name="country">
<c:forEach var="country" items="${countries}">
<option value="${country}">${country.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
--%>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="address" value="${address}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" value="${phone}" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Market Cap:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="marketCap" value="${marketCap}" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table align = "center" class="table" cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<td><input type="reset" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" /></td>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Model, Organization:

```
@Entity
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    //I should assign "Country" object to this field
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="country")
    private Country country;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private Long market_cap;

    public Organization(Integer id, String name, Country country, String address, String phone, Long market_cap) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.market_cap = market_cap;
    }
...// getters and setters
```

Model, Country:

```
@Entity
public class Country {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id_country;
    private String name;
    private String isocode;

    public Country() {
    }

public Country(Integer id_country, String name, String isocode) {
    this.id_country = id_country;
    this.name = name;
    this.isocode = isocode;
} ...//getters and setters
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addOrganization() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("add");
    Organization organization = new Organization();
    modelAndView.addObject("organization", organization);
    List<Country> countries = countryService.listOfCountries();
    modelAndView.addObject("countries", countries);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: You don't mention how you trigger this error

Comment: **Comment from Alexandre Picard-Lemieux** : What is the name of the method for the name ?

Comment: After click on submit button in ui

Comment: So don't you think the important bit is the way to build the form and the submit method ? We probably don't care of the code you posted

Comment: Sorry, guys, sometimes I don't know what can be useful. So, maybe I understood you not correctly, but I edited jsp part of post

Comment: Being able to narrow a problem down to its source is the first step to be a good programmer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `POST` but requiring `GET`. I don't know much about `@RequestMapping`, but this seems pretty obvious that there is a problem there. Finally, your form has no `action`, so it has little chance to do anything.